# What files am I working on?

Tags: linux, git, bash, terminal, git-flow

A question I frequently ask my terminal is:

What files am I working on? (including committed files)

The answer is usually gotten by this command

```
git diff my_current_work_branch..master_branch | grep diff
```

this gives me a crude list of files that I'm currently working on.

Is there a more elegant way to get this info? All I want to ask git is,

what files does this branch add/modify/delete, relative to the master branch.

Comment: Try the `--stat` flag for `git diff`

Comment: Are you looking for 'git status'?

Comment: git status wouldn't work because most of the work is already committed, (not merged in to master yet)

Comment: Then use `git status --cached`.

Comment: error: unknown option `cached'

Comment: Sorry, I meant `git diff --stat --cached`.

Comment: git diff --stat --cached returns no output for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git diff`.  If all you want is the names of files that differ, you can use the `--name-only`.

```
git diff --name-only master my_branch
```

or if you're actually checked out to my_branch

```
git diff --name-only master HEAD
```

or if you want to include uncommitted changes

```
git diff --name-only master
```

Comment: `git diff --name-only master` looks like the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

`diffstat` is a handy tool

```
git diff my_current_work_branch..master_branch` | diffstat -l
```

will show you each file that's been modified in the diff output.